# Back transform time series after differencing with multiple lags

Tags: python, time-series

I've a time series which I have differenced with a lag 4 to handle seasonality:

```
data['sales_diff_4'] =data['Sales'] -data['Sales'].shift(4)
```

Now after making predictions, I need to back transform the data.
How can I achieve that?

I've tried multiple things, I can back transform series in case of lag 1 using cumsum function, though I'm not able to back transform for higher lags.

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible example